# Unix - Invalid character in date/time specification

Tags: date, unix, aix, invalid-characters

I am trying to find last day of the month.
Date in DDMMYYYY format.

```
#!/bin/bash

start_date=01092018

end_date=$(date +%m%Y -d "$start_date +1 month")
echo $end_date
```

Expected Result :30092018

But it gives below error :
`Invalid character in date/time specification.
Usage :date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]`

Comment: Aix!date doesn't know GNU extensions. You could use Perl for such calculations. Example:  https://github.com/lzsiga/pldate `perl pldate set 20180901 add-month 1 printf %m%Y`

Answer (score 0):

AIX date do not support `-d`. So you can't use constructions like `date -d`. For reference you can check [AIX date man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/d_commands/date.html)

Nut you can try something in perl:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le '@x=localtime; if($x[4]!=0) {$x[4]++} else {$x[4]=11;$x[5]++};print strftime ("%Y-%m-%d", @x)'
```